# copy child nodes between 2 xmls in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have 2 XML files
First XML file :

```
<task>
  <name/>
  <transfer>
    <request version="6.00" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FileTransfer.xsd">
      <managedTransfer>
        <originator>
          <hostName>host.corp.</hostName>
          <userID>jenkins</userID>
        </originator>
        <sourceAgent QMgr="${SourceQm}" agent="${SourceAgent}"/>
        <destinationAgent QMgr="${DestQm}" agent="${DestAgent}"/>
        <transferSet priority="0">
          <metaDataSet>
            <metaData key="site">${MdSite}</metaData>
            <metaData key="businessSourceSystem">${MdSourceSystem}</metaData>
            <metaData key="businessTargetSystem">${MdTargetSystem}</metaData>
            <metaData key="wricef">${MdWricef}</metaData>
          </metaDataSet>
        </transferSet>
        <job>
          <name>${MonitorName}</name>
        </job>
      </managedTransfer>
    </request>
  </transfer>
</task>
```

Second XML file  :

```
<task>
  <name/>
  <transfer>
    <request version="6.00" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FileTransfer.xsd">
      <managedTransfer>
        <originator>
          <hostName>HOST.corp</hostName>
          <userID>jenkins</userID>
        </originator>
        <sourceAgent QMgr="${SourceQm}" agent="${SourceAgent}"/>
        <destinationAgent QMgr="${DestQm}" agent="${DestAgent}"/>
        <transferSet priority="0">
        </transferSet>
        <job>
          <name>${MonitorName}</name>
        </job>
      </managedTransfer>
    </request>
  </transfer>
</task>
```

i want to take all the child nodes under metaDataSet and move them from one file to another

i got a bit lost with the XML functions in powershell 
any direction will be welcomed

thanks !

Comment: Which child nodes? Which xml functions have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it

`$ENV:workspace="C:\TEMP\XMLTRANS\"
$from = [xml](Get-Content $env:workspace\from.xml)
$to = [xml](Get-Content $env:workspace\from2.xml)
foreach ($node in $from.tasks.task.transfer.request.managedTransfer.transferSet.metaDataSet) {
$to.tasks.task.transfer.request.managedTransfer.transferSet.AppendChild($to.ImportNode($node,$true))}
$to.Save('C:\TEMP\XMLTRANS\last1.xml')`

hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a blog post about adding an XML node into a config, which might help you here. Here is the snippit:

```
$global:pathToConfig = "$PSScriptRoot\DistributedCacheService.exe.config" #put your path here

#force the config into an XML
$xml = [xml](get-content $pathToConfig)

#build new node by hand and force it to be an XML object
$newNode = [xml]@"
<appSettings>
 <add key="backgroundGC" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
"@

#add new node AFTER the configsections node
$xml.configuration.InsertAfter($xml.ImportNode($newNode.appSettings, $true), $xml.configuration.configsections)

#save file
$xml.Save("$pathToConfig.CHANGED.XML")
```

Your `$newNode` will just need to come from the properties of the other file by looping over child nodes.

Hope that helps!